# Bootstrap button to toggle background-image of body

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, button, background

I am trying to toggle the background-image with a bootstrap button.

I have in css...

```
body { 
   background-image: url('img/myimage_1.gif');
}
```

in html...

```
<button type="button" id="bkgchange" class="btn" data-toggle="button">Change the background</button>
```

and in script...

```
$( 'bkgchange' ).click(function() {
    $( #body ).css( 'background-image', '~/img/myimage_2.gif' );
});
```

And it's not working?! Any pointers. I am aware that it is unconventional to want to mess with body attributes, I cannot put the image as a div background or in a container because it does not behave itself...

Alternatives as welcome as straight up solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$( '#bkgchange' ).click(function() {
    $('body').css( 'background-image', 'url(/img/myimage_2.gif)' );
});
```

`bkgchange` is your button's `id`, so if you want to access it by jQuery, you need to place `#` before it. like `$('#bkgchange')` and you want to access `body` element from page so u need to access it via `$('body')` instead of `$(#body)`.

For placing `background-image`, pattern for it is `url(path-of-image)`, and you can not use `~/` with url as css not know about it that it should refer to root directory, you can try with `/` to refer root directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( '#bkgchange' ).click(function() {
   $('body').css( 'background-image', 'url(http://terangatimes.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/html-pointing-sign-clipart.jpg)' );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/B72sv/

Your missing the `#` to get  your bkgchange button by id.  And your `body` does not need a `#` your not selecting it by id.

Also your missing the `url(` on your css and make sure your the url to your image is the complete path.

`$( 'bkgchange' ).click(function() {
    $( #body ).css( 'background-image', '~/img/myimage_2.gif' );
});`

Comment: @gl2748 please mark an answer as accepted if it answered your question, otherwise give feedback on what is not resolved. Thanks